# Delphi: Internal Error: AV004C8D4A-R00000020-0

Tags: delphi, compilação, delphi-10

Obtive o seguinte erro ao compilar um projeto no Delphi 10.2.2:

> `[dcc32 Fatal Error] Internal Error: AV004C8D4A-R00000020-0.`

Não encontrei nada a respeito deste código de erro.

- Alguém saberia informar do que se trata?
- É erro do Delphi ou poderia ser componente de terceiros?

Comment: Já tentou reiniciar o Delphi?

Comment: Já, acontece há dias.

Comment: Acontece somente com um projeto específico? Ou com qualquer projeto?

Comment: Olá, Andey. Acontecia apenas com um projeto em específico, porém o mesmo rodava em outros computadores normalmente.

Comment: O problema possivelmente estava na versão do Delphi 10.2.2. O mesmo foi desinstalado e foi instalado o 10.2 sem o update. O projeto funciona normalmente nessa versão.